# End(xlDown) for single rows

Tags: vba, excel, loops, range

I have a macro that is working 99% of the time, but giving me trouble with one portion. I have data that is split into different size groups depending on certain parameters. The groups range from 1 row to as many at 10+.  I am trying to copy each of the "groups" and paste into a template sheet and save which I've figured out.

```
 Row  Column B  Column C
1      ASDF      a
2      SDF       a
3      WIRO      a
4      VNDH      a
5 
6      FIJDK     b
7      DFKIEL    b
8 
9      DLFKD     c
10 
11     OYPTK     d
12     SSAODKJ   d
13     SKJSJ     d
```

Where I'm having trouble is Row 9 where Column b B = DLFKD and Column C = C

**Desired Output:**
Copy only row 9

**Actual Output:**
Copying Rows 9- 11

Existing Macro:
Data begins on Row 5.

```
Sub templatecopy()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim N As Long
Dim name As String


'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = ActiveWorkbook

'Set R
R = 5

'start Loop
Do Until N = 96
Set y = Workbooks.Open("F:\Logistics Dashboard\Customs Macro\Cover Sheet Template.xlsx")

'set N
N = Range("B" & R).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

'Now, copy Container Numbers from x and past to y(template):
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R & ":C" & N).Copy
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").PasteSpecial

'save as Name of Vessel
name = "F:\Logistics Dashboard\Customs Macro\" & y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").Value & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=name

'Close template after saving to reset:
y.Close



'set R equal to new row to start
R = N + 2


Loop

End Sub
```

The issue is with how I am setting "N". Its having trouble distinguishing Row 9 where its just one row of data.

Comment: Your issue is likely that *most* of the time when you set `N = Range("B" & R)...` that workbook has the active worksheet that you want. Other times it's probably a different one. Use a fully qualified reference to the specific sheet you need, either `Sheet1.Range("B" ...` or `x.Sheets("MyWorksheet").Range("B"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correct sheet selected this line of code should select the ranges on your sheet:

```
Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B:C").specialcells(xlcelltypeconstants,23).select
```

You'll need to add another line to account for formula as well as constants.

```
Public Sub FindRegionsOnSheet()

    Dim sAddress As String
    Dim aAddress() As String
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("F:\Logistics Dashboard\Customs Macro\Cover Sheet Template.xlsx")
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find all ranges of constant & formula values in column B:C.
    With wsSource.Columns(2).Resize(, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        sAddress = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Address(0, 0) & ","
        sAddress = sAddress & .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Address(0, 0)
        If Right(sAddress, 1) = "," Then sAddress = Left(sAddress, Len(sAddress) - 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Place within an array.
    If Not sAddress = vbNullString Then
        If InStr(1, sAddress, ",") = 0 Then
            ReDim aAddress(0 To 0)
            aAddress(0) = "'" & wsSource.Name & "'!" & sAddress
        Else
            aAddress = Split(sAddress, ",")
            For x = LBound(aAddress) To UBound(aAddress)
                aAddress(x) = "'" & wsSource.Name & "'!" & aAddress(x)
            Next x
        End If
    End If

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Not sure how what you're doing once moved to the Target book......
    'Think this is correct, but test first...
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For Each vItem In aAddress
        wsTarget.Cells.Clear
        Range(vItem).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A14")
        wbTarget.SaveCopyAs "F:\Logistics Dashboard\Customs Macro\" & wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14") & ".xlsx"
    Next vItem

    wbTarget.Close

End Sub
```

The `23` in the `SpecialCells` indicates what types of cells to include in the result:

```
XlSpecialCellsValue constants   Value

xlErrors                          16 
xlLogical                         4 
xlNumbers                         1 
xlTextValues                      2
```

These values can be added together to return more than one type (total = 23). The default is to select all constants or formulas, no matter what the type.... so probably don't need the 23 at all.

Comment: Hi Darren. I am getting a "Compile error: Method or data member not found" on the command towards the end 
wbTarget.SaveCopyAs "F:\Logistics Dashboard\Customs Macro\" & wsTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").Value & ".xlsx"


The debugger is highlighting the wsTarget.Sheets section

Comment: The proper place to save was wbTarget.SaveCopyAs "F:\Logistics Dashboard\Customs Macro\" & wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14") & ".xlsx"

Comment: Good spot. Sorry, didn't test that part of the code.

Comment: How would I need to amend this if I have columns next to constants, where some have values and some don't. I want to copy those in the range as well.

Comment: Just extend the range it's looking at.  `With wsSource.Columns(2).Resize(, 2)` this looks at columns B:C.  `With wsSource.Columns(2).Resize(, 3)` this looks at columns B:D.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Or you could change the size of the range when you copy: `Range(vItem).Resize(, 3).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range....`